# Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

After upgrade Android Studio to 2.2.3 it shows an error with:

> IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0
>   rc4=24.0.0 rc4 and 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to folder `ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION/build-tools` and delete `24.0.0-preview` (or another folders)

Or of course you can go over `Android SDK Manager` / `Android Studio > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Show Package Details` and uncheck preview and older RC versions. This make the same action as just delete build-tools/24... folder.

Answer (score 7):

Had this occur recently after updating a few bits.

My solution was to open the `Preferences` in Android Studio, browse to `Android SDK` -> `SDK Tools`, you will most likely see multiple copies of `24.0.0 rc4` (one with a dash instead of a space in the version name) under `Android SDK Build-Tools`. Uninstall both copies by unchecking them, and then hitting `Apply`. Once uninstalled, the list should go back to showing only one `24.0.0` version called `24-rc4`, install this and resync Gradle.

It might also help to change the `buildToolsVersion` in your Gradle files to `24-rc4`.

Answer (score 0):

this problem maybe android N preview and android N used same build version(24). So the mtrakal's answer is right. U can find build-tools has two 24.0.0 rc3 has installed.

Comment: This should be a comment