# Not able to open "Project Structure" in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created new project in studio. Code works fine without any issue.
But I am facing issue on opening Project Structure.

On click on File -> Project Structure, it's not showing Project Structure dialog
but, in bottom of studio, it's showing error like below

```
4:16:06 PM IllegalArgumentException: 
Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4 and 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4
```

[image: IllegalArgumentException error]

Can any body know how to solve this issue.
My Android studio version 2.1.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745972/multiple-entries-with-same-key-24-0-0-rc4-24-0-0-rc4)

Comment: I could read, but how to solve?

Comment: in the upper link follow instruction of `sixones Answer`.

Comment: Oh okay, I did't recognize it's link.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK location and installed needed libraries.

Comment: But it will not work, its done already, I have N, M and kitkat fully installed and updated. you could have put comment instead of answering separably.