# Can't open 'Project Structure' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've noticed that for some reason I am not able to open Project Structure in android studio anymore.

It shows the following error in the Event log :

```
IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4 and 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745972/multiple-entries-with-same-key-24-0-0-rc4-24-0-0-rc4

Comment: it didn't help , unfortunately

Comment: any help with that .. ? please